# Service Function not running separate function call (Angular 7)

Tags: angular

I am trying to have a separate function run when calling a function in a service.

Here's a simple example

```
foo() {
    this.bar();
    console.log('foo');
}

bar() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

When running my version of the code, I see the console.log('foo') working, but not bar

Basically, every time a specific function (A) runs, I need to fire another function (B) to populate data that will get pulled later, but needs to be ready immediately when I need to display it. For context, function B will be saving the data into state.

I was asked to share the real code. Here it is:

```
    getMenuByHandoffType(locationID: number, handoffType: HandoffType): Observable<Menu> {
        if (isNaN(locationID as any)) { // URL contains a slug
            return this.cmsService.getSingleLocationBySlug(locationID.toString()).pipe(switchMap(locationInfo => {
                return this.getMenuByHandoffType(Number(locationInfo.menu_id), handoffType);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log('Getting Menu');
            return this.apiService.getCategories(locationID).pipe(switchMap(pages => {
                this.populateLeadThroughs(locationID).pipe(map(res => {
                    this.leadthroughs = res;
                    return
                }));
                const menu = this.mapping.categoriesToMenu(locationID, pages);
                return this.contentService.getMenuWithImages(deMenu);
            }));
        }
    }


    populateLeadThroughs(siteID: number) {
        const leads: any[] = [];
        const order: Order = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('Order'));
         return this.apiService.getLeadThroughs(siteID).pipe(map(leadthroughRes => {
            leadthroughRes.forEach((leadThrough, index) => {
                this.apiService.getLeadThroughItemsByGroupAndPickupTime(siteID, leadThrough.Id, order.orderReadyTimestamp).pipe(map(groupRes => {
                    leadThrough.Items = groupRes;
                    leads[leadThrough['Id']] = leadThrough;
                    console.log(leads);
                }));
            });
            return leads;
        }));
    }
```

I also tested:

```
this.leadthroughs = this.populateLeadthroughs(locationID);
```

and I had no luck

Comment: The code above runs as expected. Do you want to share the real code, to understand what goes wrong?

Comment: @StPaulis I went ahead and added it. The API service does all of the network calls and the mapping just reformats the data to match the models on the front end

Comment: OK, Now I understand your problem. `this.populateLeadThroughs(locationID).pipe(map(res => {
                    this.leadthroughs = res;
                    return
                }));`
This code is never fired because you didn't subscribe to that code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you creating an observable with that code

```
this.populateLeadThroughs(locationID).pipe(map(res => {
                this.leadthroughs = res;
                return;
            }));
```

And you never subscribe on it so it never runs. I change your code to this:

```
getMenuByHandoffType(locationID: number, handoffType: HandoffType): Observable<Menu> {
    if (isNaN(locationID as any)) { // URL contains a slug
        return this.cmsService.getSingleLocationBySlug(locationID.toString()).pipe(switchMap(locationInfo => {
            return this.getMenuByHandoffType(Number(locationInfo.menu_id), handoffType);
        }));
    } else {
        console.log('Getting Menu');
        return this.apiService.getCategories(locationID).pipe(
            switchMap(pages => {
                this.populateLeadThroughs(locationID).subscribe(res => 
                    {
                        this.leadthroughs = res;
                    });
                const menu = this.mapping.categoriesToMenu(locationID, pages);
                return this.contentService.getMenuWithImages(deMenu);
        }));
    }
}


populateLeadThroughs(siteID: number) {
    const leads: any[] = [];
    const order: Order = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('Order'));
     return this.apiService.getLeadThroughs(siteID).pipe(map(leadthroughRes => {
        leadthroughRes.forEach((leadThrough, index) => {
            this.apiService.getLeadThroughItemsByGroupAndPickupTime(siteID, leadThrough.Id, order.orderReadyTimestamp).pipe(map(groupRes => {
                leadThrough.Items = groupRes;
                leads[leadThrough['Id']] = leadThrough;
                console.log(leads);
            }));
        });
        return leads;
    }));
}
```

But be careful, that if you observable does not auto unsubscribe (Auto Unsubscribe happens only in Http Calls usually), you have to unsubscribe on your own.